# Add div code base on input attr title value in jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to add div base on input attr title, i mean to say i want to add div where i have input title=date-of-graduation

```
  <div class="personalisation_input">
    <input type="text" value=""  title="date-of-graduation">
  </div>
  <div class="personalisation_input">
    <input type="text" value=""  title="date-of-age">
  </div>
  <div class="personalisation_input">
    <input type="text" value=""  title="date-of-graduation">
  </div>
```

**Need Output like that**

```
  <div class="personalisation_input">
    <input type="text" value=""  title="date-of-graduation">
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="personalisation_input">
    <input type="text" value=""  title="date-of-age">
  </div>
  <div class="personalisation_input">
    <input type="text" value=""  title="date-of-graduation">
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: $('input').attr( 'title', 'date-of-graduation' )..after('<div class="bottom_slogan">If only Year is entered. We will supply the authentic date.</div>');  i used that code , but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ["attribute equals" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the correct `input` element, and the [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method to insert some content immediately after it:

```
$("input[title='date-of-graduation']").after("<div>test</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.personalisation_input input').each(function(){
 if($(this).attr('title') == 'date-of-graduation'){
     $(this).after('<div>Test</div>')
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

​

```
    $("input[title='date-of-graduation']").parent().append("<div>test</div>");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```